# this.subject() returns already destroyed object at beginning of test

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-qunit

I have several qunit tests for my ember model.

When I try to save my model, it raises

`Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object`

And when I run this `this.subject().get('isDestroyed')` it returns true.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up solving the problem for me: https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit/issues/83#issuecomment-95990645